# are all bluetooth devices bi-directional

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I am not a developer (anymore - retired 20 years ago), but want to work on a project that will use a bluetooth bracelet to initiate an action on a cellphone. I need to know if all bluetooth devices are bi-directional. Can the bracelet initiate an action on the cellphone? The hardware distributor says no, but I don't know if he is a salesperson without technical knowledge, or if this bracelet is truly just one directional and only able to receive info from the cellphone.

Here are the limited specifications that I have for the bracelet model:

Product Name: Health Bracelet
bluetooth standard: 2.1+EDR
Application: Android
screen: OLED 0.91 inch
Battery: 80 mAh
Certifications: CE, RoHS, BQB

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the lowest level Bluetooth devices both send and receive data - they need to acknowledge connections and data transfers.

Whether a tap on a bracelet can initiate an action on the phone depends on the software in the phone and the device.

The device you have mentioned uses Bluetoth 2.1 so you cannot write custom software in iOS unless it is certified thought the Apple MFi program